# Home directory incorrect in thunar

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xubuntu

I am running xubuntu 22.04.3.  I renamed my account from CP203 to CP.  I then modified the /etc/passwd file so the the home directory is /home/CP.  But when I go to thunar and click on Documents or Downloads, it tells me the CP203 directory does not exist.  Is there another location I need to update?
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip.  I figured out that the shortcut in Thunar on the left hand side can be deleted and I can drag the correct folder over to the devices area.